# error in django URLconf, I can't start the local server, an error pops up in the screenshot

Tags: python, html, css, django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncu16.png)
I have a ready-made html template with css. It seems to have done everything correctly, but it does not work.

project location C:\Projects\brew\brewtopia

location of the application C:\Projects\brew\brewtopia\users

location of the main urls.py C:\Projects\brew\brewtopia\brewtopia\urls.py

location urls.py in the app C:\Projects\brew\brewtopia\users\urls.py

location of views.py in the app C:\Projects\brew\brewtopia\users\views.py

html layout C:\Projects\brew\brewtopia\users\templates\users\Brewtopia.

folder static C:\Projects\brew\brewtopia\users\static

version django 4.1
python 3.11

I've been sitting with this problem for a day now, I've tried everything, people with experiences help me, I just started learning django

here is the code in the urls,py of the main project

```
`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('"', include('users.urls')),
]`
```

here is the code in urls,py in the application

```
`from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
      path('Brewtopia', views.Brewtopia_view, name='brewtopia')
]`
```

here is the code in views.py in the app

```
`from django.shortcuts import render

def Brewtopia_view(request):
    return render(request, 'Brewtopia.html')`
```

in the main settings.py I have completed this

```
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]`
```

Comment: You have a two available link of your application in your screenshoot

localhost:8000/admin and localhost:8000/Brewtopia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want set localhost:8000/Brewtopia as index, change the code in urls.py in the application like that

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Brewtopia_view, name='brewtopia')
]
```